# nodemailer for reset password got mail but there don't get link for connection

Tags: javascript, smtp, nodemailer

Problem is in the mail why  cannot get link for redirecting to the page for update password only got mail with token numbers.

Here is some info of the code here is controller code:

```js
const resetPassword = async (req, res) => {

    let smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        sercice: 'Gmail',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: process.env.USER,
            pass: process.env.PASSWORD
        },
        tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
    })

    crypto.randomBytes(32, (err, buffer) => {
        if (err) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'invalid token!' })

        const token = buffer.toString("hex")
        User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
            .then(user => {
                if (!user) return res.status(422).json({ msg: 'User with this email does not exists!' })

                user.resetToken = token;
                user.expireToken = Date.now() + 3600000

                user.save()
                    .then((result) => {
                        smtpTransport.sendMail({
                            to: user.email,
                            from: 'banbranimir0@gmail.com',
                            subject: 'Reset Password',
                            html: `
                            <h2>You requested for password reset</h2>
                            <h4>Please click on<a href="${process.env.RESET}/reset/${token}"> Here</a > to reset password!</h4 >
                        `
                        })
                        res.json({ msg: 'Check your email.' })
                    })
            })
    })
}


const newPassword = async (req, res) => {

    const newPassword = req.body.password
    const sendToken = req.body.token
    User.findOne({ resetToken: sendToken, expireToken: { $gt: Date.now() } })
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) return res.status(422).json({ msg: 'User with this email does not exists!' })

            //hash password
            bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 12)
                .then(hashedPassword => {
                    user.password = hashedPassword
                    user.resetToken = undefined
                    user.expireToken = undefined
                    user.save()
                        .then((savedUser) => {
                            res.json({ msg: 'Password Reset Successfully!' })
                        })
                })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Something went wrong!' })
        })
}
```

and here is .env for RESET=http://localhost:3000

and this is mail what I got

You requested for password reset
Please click on<a href="http://localhost:3000/reset/587183961c760496e721fe72274e350ecaf3b6210dad7b7c023dd8c80ccdae6c> Here to reset password!

Comment: Try to add `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }` in the mail options

Comment: thnx for help now it's working

Comment: if adding `headers` solved the problem I will add it as an answer to make it easier for other people to find the solution. Please clean up your question to make it easier for people to understand. StackOverflow is not centered around individuals, your question needs to benefit more than just you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that OP hasn't seen my comment, I will post the answer just in case.

So yeah, basically whenever you are trying to send a mail with included `HTML`, in most libraries you will have to specify that the mail should interprate the message as `HTML`, else its just going to display the data as plain text. This is like the payload type when returning data from an API as in `text/json` or `text/text` or `text/xml` or `text/bytes` etc.

In this case, the content type is `text/html`. You need to include the `Content-Type` header with that value in the request options object, so the corrected object would look something like this:

```
{
    to: user.email,
    from: 'banbranimir0@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Reset Password',
    html: `
        <h2>You requested for password reset</h2>
        <h4>Please click on<a href="${process.env.RESET}/reset/${token}"> Here</a > to reset password!</h4 >
    `
    headers: {
        "Content-Type" : "text/html"
    }
}
```

notice the `headers` property.